# Integral of $x^3e^{-x^8}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been trying to solve this problem using integration by parts, with some luck. Unfortunately, I'm getting a counter intuitive (read: wrong) answer. If someone could point out the issue with my integration, that would be great. 
For the first integration by parts, let $u = e^{-x^8}$ and $du = -8x^7e^{-x^8}$, with $dv = x^3$ and $v=\frac{x^4}{4}$. Therefore:
$$\int_a^b x^3e^{-x^8}dx=\frac{x^4e^{-x^8}}{4}|_a^b + 2\int_a^bx^{11}e^{-x^8}dx.$$
Using integration by parts again on $\int_a^bx^{11}e^{-x^8}dx$, I split this up like so: 
$$\int_a^bx^{11}e^{-x^8}dx=\int_a^bx^4(x^{7}e^{-x^8})dx.$$ Now I take $u=x^4$, $du=4x^3$, $dv = x^{7}e^{-x^8}$, and $v=\frac{e^{-x^8}}{-8}$. 
Therefore, 
$$\int_a^bx^{11}e^{-x^8}dx=\frac{x^{4}e^{-x^8}}{-8}|_a^b + \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b x^{3}e^{-x^8}.$$
After plugging this integral back into the original integration by parts, we get cancellation with both $uv$ terms, which makes our integral $0$. This makes no sense, as one can graph the function and see that it is not $0$ everywhere, so its integral over some interval must not be $0$. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Do a change of variable $u=x^4$ you will get
$${\displaystyle\int}x^3\mathrm{e}^{-x^8}\,\mathrm{d}x =\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}}{8}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{-u^2}}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}\,\mathrm{d}u =\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\left(u\right)}{8}=\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\left(x^4\right)}{8} $$
where $\operatorname{erf}$ is the [Gauss error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). I think this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the change of variable $u = x^4$. You should be able to make the error function appear pretty quickly.

Also it seems your changes of variable are incorrect:

$du = 4 x^3 dx$

$dx = \frac{du}{4x^3}$

So you can replace $dx$ in the integral.

Comment: Can you further explain the mistake in the change of variables?